# Trying to get data from external api with basic authentication using node and https

Tags: node.js, api, https, basic-authentication

I am trying to get data from an external api, which requires basic authentication. I am using node + express, and the https module.

I am not getting any errors, simply a 401 response status code, I just don't get to log in.

Also, on postman I do get the response without any problems. Which means that both the url and the authentication data I am passing are correct.

Really stuck here. Any help will be massively appreciated!

Manel

My code:

```
const express = require('express');
const https = require("https");  
const basic = require('basic-authorization-header');

 
const app = express();

const auth = {
  'Authorization': basic("username", "password"),
};

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    const url = "https://dictapi.lexicala.com/search?source=global&language=en&text=working&analyzed=true"

    https.get(url, auth, (response) => {
        console.log(response.statusCode);
        console.log(auth);
        response.responseType="text";
        response.on("data", (data)=> {
            const translationLot = JSON.parse(data)
            console.log(translationLot);
        })
    })
    res.send("Server is up and running")
  });

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 7070;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`));
```

Output on terminal:

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
Server is running on port 7070
401
{ Authorization: 'Basic TW5M2FzOMQ==' }
{ status: 401, message: 'Not logged in' }
```

Answer (score 0):

As i read in the docs

`options.auth`'s type is `string`, so i suggest trying something like:

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    const url = "https://dictapi.lexicala.com/search?source=global&language=en&text=working&analyzed=true"
    const options = {
      auth : 'username:password' //here you put your credentials
    }

    https.get(url, options, (response) => {
        console.log(response.statusCode);
        console.log(auth);
        response.responseType="text";
        response.on("data", (data)=> {
            const translationLot = JSON.parse(data)
            console.log(translationLot);
        })
    })
    res.send("Server is up and running")
  });
```

I found the info [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#httprequestoptions-callback)

Answer (score -2):

Did you enter your actual username and password here?

basic("**username**", "**password**")

Replace username with your actual username and password with your actual password between the quotes.